# make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $path

Tags: node.js, macos, npm, homebrew, npm-install

I am checking to "make sure that /usr/local/bin is in your $path"

When i run echo $PATH this shows up:

/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/Users//.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3@global/bin:/Users//.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.6.3/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users//.rvm/bin"

Is this the same? Asking because I ran into some problems trying to change the path

Comment: Yes, each colon separates each directory in $PATH, since `/usr/loca/bin` is there, so it should be in your $PATH.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!

Comment: Did you remove your username from the sections like `/Users//.rvm/whatever`? If not, there's something wrong with those parts, because I'm pretty sure they should be something like `/Users/wlfbbz/.rvm/whatever`.

Comment: Yes I replaced it with <username> when I was posting here, thanks gordon!